# Getting Windows 8 to display different pictures on each display desktop

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, windows-update, desktop, slideshow

Until today, my computer has always run a slideshow on my dual screen desktop.

Each screen would display a different picture, and would change alternately. In other words, if the picture was set to change every half an hour, then **one** picture would change, then the other, effectively meaning that each monitor changed every hour.

These pictures were set to fill the screen, and did so very well indeed.

However, this morning there was either an update or a crash, not sure which because I wasn't looking. There are no longer two pictures, just one duplicated, and the resolution of both is the same, so it doesn't fill the larger screen.

I have tried restarting the computer and explorer, reshuffling display settings and theme settings, and unplugging it and plugging it back in again. And scratching my head.

Does anyone know why this has stopped, or how to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it will eventually sort itself out, but I didn't do anything to make that happen.

I'm still flummoxed, but at least it's back...

(trying to mark the question as answered, or similar. New to posting questions though, only ever answered before...)

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick your desktop and choose `Personalize` (or personalization) forgot the name that was used in windows 8.

Go to your background settings, and change how the background is presented. Some settings will keep the same background across different monitors, such as tile, while others (stretch for example) will use different images across different monitors.

I don't have a windows 8 machine here with me to look what the exact names are and how they function, but its easy enough to test and you'll see the reaction straight away.

Comment: I tried all that, unfortunately, with no luck.

That said, I've now got it back. I have no idea how... :D